# OpenCV Mat masking based on condition in c#

Tags: python, c#, c++, opencv

I am trying to implement MaxRGB filter in OpenCvSharp. I have found similar [solution in Python](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/28/implementing-the-max-rgb-filter-in-opencv/), but I don't know how to write `R[R<M]=0` in OpenCvSharp or in C++. It means to set 0 for value in channel where value is less than value in mask.

```
def max_rgb_filter(image):
# split the image into its BGR components
(B, G, R) = cv2.split(image)

# find the maximum pixel intensity values for each
# (x, y)-coordinate,, then set all pixel values less
# than M to zero
M = np.maximum(np.maximum(R, G), B)
R[R < M] = 0
G[G < M] = 0
B[B < M] = 0

# merge the channels back together and return the image
return cv2.merge([B, G, R])
```

What is the C#/C++ alternative for `R[R < M] = 0`? Or will I have to use regular loops?

Comment: Maybe combine [matrix expression](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions) and [Mat::setTo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) ?

Comment: in c++ you can use `Mat TM = R < M;` it will work. then index of non zero of `TM` should be used to set Zero for `R`, `G` and `B`. I think you can use loop for 2nd part